# (Proof Verification). The set of all subsequential limits of a sequence is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I am essentially using the same idea from Rudin PMA Theorem 3.7, but without the $\delta=d(q,p_{n_1})$ stuff cause I think it's unnecessary and the proof will be better off without it, I just don't know if I did things correctly,

> Lemma 7.5. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence from a metric space $M$ and let $x\in E$ (where $E$ is defined later below). Then for any $\epsilon>0$ and $m_1\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an $m_2>m_1$ such that $d(x,x_{m_2})<\epsilon.$

Proof. Since $x\in E$, $x=\lim{(x_{k(n)})}$, so for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $N$ such that $d(x,x_{k(n)})<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. Let $m_1\in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Let $m_3=\text{max}\{m_1,N\}+1$, then both $k(m_3)>m_1$ and $m_3\geq N$ are true. Set $m_2=k(m_3)$, then both $m_2>m_1$ and $d(x,x_{m_2})=d(x,x_{k(m_3)})<\epsilon$ as desired. $\Box$

> Theorem 7.6. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence from a metric space $M$, then the set                        $E=\{\lim{(p_n)} \ \vert \ (p_n) \text{ is a subsequence of }(x_n)\}$ is closed in $M$.

Proof. Let $q$ be a limit point of $E$, then we need to show that $q\in E$. To do that, we will construct a subsequence of $(x_n)$ which converges to $q$. Set $n_1=1$. For some $k\geq 2$, suppose $n_1,\ldots,n_{k-1}$ has been found, then we need to find $n_k$. Since $q$ is a limit point of $E$, there exists an $x\in E$ such that $d(q,x)<2^{-k}$. Furthermore, since $x\in E$, it is the limit of some subsequence of $(x_n)$, and by lemma 7.5, we can find an $m>n_{k-1}$ such that $d(x,x_{m})<2^{-k}$. Set $n_k=m$, then,

$$d(q,x_{n_k})\leq d(q,x)+d(x,x_{n_k})<2^{1-k}, \quad \text{for each }k=2,3,\ldots$$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary, we can surely find a $K$ large enough (we can assume $K\neq 1)$ such that $2^{1-k}<\epsilon$ for all $k\geq K$. Therefore, $d(q,x_{n_k})<2^{1-k}<\epsilon$ for all $k\geq K$, i.e, $(x_{n_k})\to q$ as desired. $\Box$

Comment: You seem to be correct. But I am still thinking why Rudin used $\delta$.

Comment: I think if Rudin didn't use $\delta$, then we would get $d(q,p_{n_i})\leq 2^{1-i}$ which is only true for $i=2,3,...$, however, upon inclusion of $\delta$, we would get $d(q,p_{n_i})\leq 2^{1-i} \delta$, which, in addition to being true for $i=2,3,...$ is also true for $i=1$ as well.

Comment: Fine. But $p_{n_1}$ itself could have been chosen such that $d(q,p_{n_1})<1$. Anyway, not much worries.

Answer (score 1):

Not an actual answer to the original question, but I'd like to present a different proof:

Given a sequence $(x_k)_{k\geq 1}$, put $E_k=\{x_k,x_{k+1},\dots\}$. Then $E_1\supseteq E_2\supseteq\dots$ Now $x\in X$ is a subsequential limit of $(x_k)_{k\geq 1}$ if and only if for any $\epsilon>0$ and $k$ there exists $n>k$ such that $d(x,x_k)<\epsilon$. That is, for any $\epsilon>0$ and $N$, the open ball of radius $r$ about $x$ intersects $E_k$. In other words, $x\in\bar{E}_k$ for all $k$.

To summarize the above, $x$ is a subsequential limit of $(x_k)_{k\geq N}$ if and only if $x\in\bar{E}_1\cap\bar{E}_2\cap\dots$ The latter, as an intersection of closed sets, is closed.